# Estoy intentando sumar pero el subtotal no suma, caso contrario que el acumulador esta sumando correctamente

Tags: c++, dev-c++

> aquí esta el código agradecería la ayuda de alguien y me explicara porque no suma el subtotal
> estoy limitado y no puedo usar otra librería además de esas dos.

```
int cantidad, i=0;
float precio, subtotal, itbms, total=0;

printf("¿Cuántos elementos de la carta desea comprar el cliente?: ");
scanf("%d",&cantidad);

do {
    printf("Valor del platillo: ");
    scanf("%f",&precio);
    total=total+precio;
    i=i+1;
}
while(i<cantidad);
        subtotal=total;
        itbms=total*0.07;
        subtotal=itbms+total;
```

Comment: *"no puedo usar otra librería además de esas dos"*. Cuales 2? Y a que te refieres con *porque no suma el subtotal*? Se nos haria mas facil ayudarte si nos dijeras: 1. El comportamiento esperado. 2. El comportamiento que estas recibiendo y 3. Unas entradas de prueba con sus esperados resultados para que podamos probar tu codigo.

Comment: las librerías que estoy utilizando son stdio.h y stdlib.h.

Comment: `  for(i=1;i<=cantidad;i++){
 printf("Introduzca el valor del platillo: \n");
 scanf("%f",&precio);
 printf("%f",&precio);
 acumulador=acumulador+precio;
 } while(i<=cantidad);
 acumulador=subtotal;
 itbms=subtotal*0.07;
 cargo=subtotal+itbms;
 printf("\n El subtotal es de: %f ",&subtotal);
 printf("\n El itbms es de: %f ",&itbms);
 printf("\n El total es de: %f ",&cargo);
 printf("\n VUELVA PRONTO ");`

Comment: Por favor, edita la pregunta y pon ahí el código ¿No ves que el código en los comentarios resulta ilegible?

Comment: @Blaster-x11 El codigo en el comentario es algo complicado de leer. Le puedes dar a [este link](https://es.stackoverflow.com/posts/452492/edit) para editar tu post, asi lo puedes colocar bien.

Comment: Ya postee la pregunta denuevo y que se de manera más legible, aquí el link https://es.stackoverflow.com/questions/452507/no-reconoce-las-variables-cu%c3%a1ndo-se-le-inserta?noredirect=1#comment805923_452507