# No reconoce las variables cuándo se le inserta

Tags: c++, dev-c++

> Estoy usando dos librerías en especificas, aquí introduje las variables, las username y password son credenciales de acceso y las demás son los acumuladores.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

char username;
int password;
char cliente;
int cantidad;
int i=1;
float precio; 
float subtotal; 
float itbms; 
float acumulador=0; 
float cargo;
```

> El proceso de aquí es una interfaz de acceso de usuario y contraseña, aquí el programa tira un error en caso de que la contraseña sea incorrecta y en caso que sea correcta te permite entrar al menú.

```
main(){
printf("Nombre \n");
printf("Grado \n");

printf("Escriba su nombre de usuario: ");
scanf("%s",&username);
printf("Escriba el código de acceso: ");
scanf("%d",&password);
    
    if(username=='D'){
    printf("Nombre de usuario correcto \n");
    if(password==2341){
    printf("Contraseña correcta, puede ingresar al sistema\n");
```

aquí inicie el menú para tomar de referencia el total

```
printf("Menu \n");
printf("a. Desayuno \n");
    printf("Pancakes y waffles con tocino y huevo frito $7.50 \n");
    printf("Huevos rancheros                        $6.75 \n");
    printf("Tostadas francesas con queso y jamón        $7.50 \n");  
    printf("Bistec de res con queso gratinado           $9.00 \n");
    printf("Crema de avena                              $5.00 \n");
    printf("Tamal                                           $3.00 \n");

printf("b. Almuerzo \n");
    printf("Sancocho interiorano                        $5.00 \n");
    printf("Chupe de camarones                      $11.90 \n");
    printf("Filete de res a la cubana               $14.50 \n");
    printf("Milanesa de filete de res a la napolitana   $17.00 \n");
    printf("Corvina en escabeche                            $16.90 \n");
    printf("Arroz negro con camarones                   $13.50 \n");
    
printf("c. Cena \n");
    printf("Lasagna de carne gratinada              $11.90 \n");
    printf("Ravioli de queso y jamon serrano        $14.50 \n");
    printf("Pizza cuatro quesos                     $9.50 \n");
    printf("Langostinos al mango                        $18.90 \n");
    printf("Caldo gallego                               $9.00 \n");
    printf("Ensalada caeser de salmon                   $10.50 \n");
    
printf("d. Postres y bebidas\n");
    printf("Flan de la casa                             $5.50 \n");
    printf("Cheesecake de dulce de leche                $6.50 \n");
    printf("Pie de limon                                $7.00 \n");
    printf("Limonada clasica                            $4.00 \n");
    printf("Espresso                                    $2.50 \n");
    printf("Jugos naturales o licuados                  $4.50 \n");
```

Aquí es dónde esta la raíz del problema, lo que no entiendo es porque no registra los datos las variables y por ende no suma.

```
printf("¿Cuántos elementos de la carta desea comprar el cliente?: ");
scanf("%d",&cantidad);

    for(i=1;i<=cantidad;i++){
    printf("Introduzca el valor del platillo: \n");
    scanf("%f",&precio);
    printf("%f",&precio);
    acumulador=acumulador+precio;
    } while(i<=cantidad);
    acumulador=subtotal;
    itbms=subtotal*0.07;
    cargo=subtotal+itbms;
    printf("\n El subtotal es de: %f ",&subtotal);
    printf("\n El itbms es de: %f ",&itbms);
    printf("\n El total es de: %f ",&cargo);
    printf("\n VUELVA PRONTO ");
        
    }else{printf("codigo de acceso erroneo, credenciales invalidadas \n");
    system ("pause");
    }
    }else{
    printf("Nombre de usuario incorrecto \n");
    system("pause");
    }
    }
```

Comment: Tienes problemas en tus `printf`, le debes de quitar los `&` antes de las variables

Comment: funciono, muchas gracias pude resolver el problema.